# Как вывести объект (ассоциативный массив) в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы

Не получается вывести (без явного цикла, методами) объект (ассоциативный массив) в текстовое поле input.

Есть массив вида:

```
arrOfData =  {2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, Q: 1, …};
function outMessage(mess) {
        let out = document.getElementById('formessage');
let anytext = mess;
out.textContent = anytext;
}
outMessage(arrOfData); //выдает [object Object] - здесь нужно вывести то что внизу
console.log(arrOfData); // выдает {2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, Q: 1, …}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
arrOfData = {
  2: 2,
  3: 2,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  Q: 1
};
var str = JSON.stringify(arrOfData); // string for textContent
// document.getElementById('formessage').textConten = str;
document.write('<div>' + str + '</div>');
```

Comment: Отлично! Огромное спасибо.